# Prove if $y \in B(x,r_1)$ then $y \in B(a,r)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> **Question:**
>
> For $x \in B(a,r)$ find $r_1$ such that $B(x,r_1) \subset B(a,r)$.
>
> That is, if $y \in B(x,r_1)$ then $y\in B(a,r)$.

I have tried drawing the following sketch:

[image]

**My attempt:**

From the sketch, we may define
$$r_1 = \frac{1}{2}(r - ||x-a||)$$
To ensure $B(x, r_1)$ always lies within $B(a,r)$.

Now if some point $y\in B(x,r_1)$ we know:
\begin{align}||y-x|| <r_1 = \frac{1}{2}(r - ||x-a||) \\
\implies 2||y-x|| < r - ||x -a|| \\
\implies 2||y-x|| + ||x-a|| <r \end{align}

Now, using the triangle inequality, we can say the following

\begin{align}
||y -x|| + ||x-a|| \leq 2||y-x|| + ||x-a|| < r \\
\implies ||y -x + x -a|| \leq ||y -x|| + || x-a|| \leq 2||y-x|| + ||x-a||  < r \\
\implies ||y-a|| \leq  || y- x|| + ||x-a|| \leq  2|| y-x|| + ||x - a|| <r \\
\implies ||y-a|| <r
\end{align}
Hence we know that $y \in B(a,r)$

Is this correct?

Comment: I find the question (meaning the one in the box, not the one if your attempt is correct) a bit strange because it seems that $B(x,r_1) \subset B(a,r)$ is already assumed. But then $y \in B(x,r_1)$ definitely implies $y \in B(a,r)$ and there is nothing to prove.

Comment: The question was given to us in short so I simply put it into words (which might have been incorrectly done). The exact question he gave us was: $y \in B(x, r_1)$ Prove $y \in B(a,r)$.

Comment: Was $r_1$ given the way you wrote it down or did that definition came from you?

Comment: He said that $r_1$ can be written as that to ensure it lies within $B(a,r)$

Comment: I am not sure about that, but maybe this was intended: For $x \in B(a,r)$ find $r_1 > 0$ such that $B(x,r_1) \subset B(a,r)$, that is, if $y \in B(x,r_1)$, then $y \in B(a,r)$.

Comment: That sounds much better! :). This was our first elementary topology lecture, so I'm sorry for things being so "scrambled". :)

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch - How will I go about doing that? :) . Any hints will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21410/discussion-between-matthias-klupsch-and-dillon).

Comment: The 2nd implication, $||y-x|| + ||x - a|| \leq ||y - x + x - a||$ seems like the reverse of the triangle inequality to me.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch - if the factor of 1/2 isn't there, then $r_1 = r - ||x-a||$ . Won't that mean the possibility of $B(x, r_1)$ touching the border of $B(a,r)$, which it's not allowed to do? Consider the case $x=a$ .. Then that would mean $r_1 =r$, which is not what we want? Or do I have this incorrect?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch - I emailed the lecturer. Your version of the question, was in fact what he meant. :)

Comment: I do not think that there will be any problem. For example in the case $x = a$, if we take $r_1 = r$, then $B(x,r_1) = B(a,r)$, so in particular $y \in B(x,r_1)$ implies $y \in B(a,r)$. But of course, there is no real drawback when adding a factor $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch - Thank you so much! :D. It makes sense now! :)